# When exactly can I use isset and GET function

Tags: php

I am following a tutorial on how to make an ecommerce site in php and my major doubt for now is on when exactly must the **isset** function be used.

So first I display all product brands on a sidebar using this code:

```
function getBrands(){
    global $con;

    $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

    while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
         $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
         $brand_name = $row_brands['brand_name'];
         echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=$brand_id'>$brand_name</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Then there is this code which is to display all the products based on the brand:

```
function get_brand_pro(){
    if(isset($_GET['brand'])){

        $brand_id = $_GET['brand'];

        global $con;

        $get_brand_pro = "select * from products where product_brand='$brand_id'"; 

        $run_brand_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_brand_pro);

        $count_brands =  mysqli_num_rows($run_brand_pro);

        if($count_brands==0){
            echo "<h3>No products associated with this brand where foundd</h3>";
        }

        while( $row_brand_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brand_pro)){

            $product_id = $row_brand_pro['product_id'];
            $product_cat = $row_brand_pro['product_cat'];
            $product_brand = $row_brand_pro['product_brand'];
            $product_title = $row_brand_pro['product_title'];
            $product_price = $row_brand_pro['product_price'];
            $product_image = $row_brand_pro['product_image'];

            echo "
                <div class='single_product'>    
                    <h3 class='product_title'>$product_title</h3>
                    <img src='admin-area/product_images/$product_image' alt='product image' width='250' height='250' />
                    <p class='product_price'>$ $product_price</p>
                    <div class='single_links'>
                        <a href='details.php?product_id=$product_id' class='details'>Details</a>
                        <a href='index.php?product_id=$product_id' class='add_cart'><button>Add to Cart</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            ";
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the isset function is working the same saying if a button is clicked.

Why exactly is it choosing isset([$_GET['brands']]) ?
Because I see that there is no attribute named brands in my database.

Hope you can correct me where am wrong.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: `brands` is a query string that was created here `echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=$brand_id'>$brand_name</a></li>";` so on the other page you first need to check if the brand is set before trying to use it

Comment: brand_id  ... its

Comment: and .. product_brand is fetch using product_brand = $brand_id ..

Comment: I hope above comments clears your understanding. Can you say exact what issue are you facing? We can help to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well `isset` determines whether the variable is set or NULL. In your code and database, you do have an attribute named product_brand which uses that value.

You get the value using this line: `$brand_id = $_GET['brand'];`
And then in your query, you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

**isset() function**

> The isset () function is used to check whether a variable is set or
>   not. If a variable is already unset with unset() function, it will no
>   longer be set. The isset() function return false if testing variable
>   contains a NULL value.

**In Your Code Explain:**

```
echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=$brand_id'>$brand_name</a></li>";
```

Here , `brands=$brand_id` is a **query String** , Which Assign the id to 'brand'
and then we check its set using `if(isset($_GET['brand']))` . and if ise Set Then,
We Get The Value Of brand in another variable ( `$brand_id` ), and Then you fetch the data in your `select ...where product_brand = '$brand_id'`.

```
if(isset($_GET['brand'])){   //Check brand Is Set Or Not in Query String 

        $brand_id = $_GET['brand'];  // If is set then assign to $brand_id variable 

        global $con;

        $get_brand_pro = "select * from products where product_brand='$brand_id'";    //Here fetch the data of product table based on $brand_id which is equal to product_brand in your product table.
```

Answer (score -1):

isset() actually check if a variable or an array is defined or not, 
Example:

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
```

The best best way to check if the value of HTTP _GET has been set to variable $name is

```
if(empty($name)){
echo 'variable $name is empty';
}
```

But if you want to check the global variable/array $_GET directly without assigning it to a variable, that is when the isset(); function is needed.
Example

```
if(!isset($_GET["name"])){
echo '$_GET["name"] is not set';
}
```

Comment: That's terrible and nonsensical use of `empty`.